# MySQL joining 2 tables in to one main table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables 'cat' and 'sub_cat' and these two tables should join or something with main table 'product'

I tried all joining methods and non of them gave me right result I want. 
I'm sure there is a method. I don't know what to call.

[Sample SQL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1vRaV5sPlAQT256QmVYMHhVQms&authuser=0)

**This is how the last query should be**
[image: This is how the last query should be]

forget about the normalization theories and every thing and I just want the last query to be like this or mysql method that I can use on this.

1. cat_id cannot be duplicate
2. s_id should also cannot be duplicate
3. like in third row there can be: cat_id but no s_id the s_id should be null
4. if there is no cat_id and no s_id both should be null like fourth row
5. p_id can be duplicate
6. can't use group by or distinct cause it doesn't give null values then as i know

only method i got closer is using left joining both cat and sub_cat to prod table but it gives me duplicate cat_id and s_id and can't use group by or distinct on this cause there should be null values.

here is the test data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat` (
    `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cat_name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `cat` (`product_id`, `cat_id`, `cat_name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'cat1'),
(2, 2, 'cat2'),
(3, 3, 'cat3'),
(1, 4, 'ca4');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prod` (
    `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `prod` (`product_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'prod1'),
(2, 'prod2'),
(3, 'pro3'),
(4, 'prod4');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_cat` (
     `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `sub_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `sub_cat_name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `sub_cat` (`product_id`, `sub_cat_id`, `sub_cat_name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'sub cat 1'),
(2, 2, 'sub cat 2'),
(1, 3, 'sub3');
```

Comment: That's nice.  Please add sample data into your question and make the effort to copy the SQL as text into the question.

Comment: I have put the sql I was testing. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1vRaV5sPlAQT256QmVYMHhVQms&authuser=0

Comment: i have put the sample code now.  thanks it was too ugly when copy past.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing in this one.prop_cat acts as you Category table,prop_subcat as your subcategory table and property as you product.

```
CREATE TABLE `prop_cat` (
  `pcat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pcat_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pcat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `prop_subcat` (
  `psubcat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pcat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `psubcat_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`psubcat_id`,`pcat_id`),
  KEY `pspc_idx` (`pcat_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `catsub` FOREIGN KEY (`pcat_id`) REFERENCES `prop_cat` (`pcat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `prop_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prop_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` double DEFAULT NULL,

  `psubcat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prop_id`),
  KEY `psub_idx` (`psubcat_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `psub` FOREIGN KEY (`psubcat_id`) REFERENCES `prop_subcat` (`pcat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



SELECT
     prop_cat.`pcat_id` AS prop_cat_pcat_id,
     prop_cat.`pcat_name` AS prop_cat_pcat_name,
     prop_subcat.`psubcat_id` AS prop_subcat_psubcat_id,
     prop_subcat.`pcat_id` AS prop_subcat_pcat_id,
     prop_subcat.`psubcat_name` AS prop_subcat_psubcat_name,
     property.`prop_id` AS property_prop_id,
     property.`prop_name` AS property_prop_name,
     property.`price` AS property_price,
     property.`location` AS property_location,
     property.`image` AS property_image,
     property.`area` AS property_area,
     property.`psubcat_id` AS property_psubcat_id,
     property.`description` AS property_description
FROM
     `prop_cat` prop_cat INNER JOIN `prop_subcat` prop_subcat ON prop_cat.`pcat_id` = prop_subcat.`pcat_id`
     INNER JOIN `property` property ON prop_subcat.`pcat_id` = property.`psubcat_id`
```

Comment: thanks again but it doesn't completely what i was hoping